# adding new resolution xrandr : crtc 1 failed

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, xrandr

I added an external monitor to my desktop computer (OS ubuntu 18.04).
Here is the `xrandr --props` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2944 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96  
   myMode        60.00  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
HDMI-2 connected 1920x1080+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 268mm
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0010acb8d042355a31
        2d1b010380301b78eac7b5a756539c27
        105054a54b00714f8180a9c0d1c00101
        010101010101023a801871382d40582c
        4500dc0c1100001e000000ff00525946
        3337374238315a35420a000000fc0044
        454c4c205332323138480a20000000fd
        00384c1e5311000a20202020202001d3
        02031ef14b90050403021101141f1213
        230907078301000065030c001000023a
        801871382d40582c4500dc0c1100001e
        011d8018711c1620582c2500dc0c1100
        009e011d007251d01e206e285500dc0c
        1100001e8c0ad08a20e02d10103e9600
        dc0c1100001800000000000000000000
        000000000000000000000000000000c1
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
  1920_1080_60 (0x12d) 172.800MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2040 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.08KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1081 end 1084 total 1118           clock  60.00Hz
```

I added the "myMode" using the steps provided here ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227876/how-to-set-custom-resolution-using-xrandr-when-the-resolution-is-not-available-i)):

```
gtf 1920 1080 60
  # 1920x1080 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 67.08 kHz; pclk: 172.80 MHz
  Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --newmode "myMode" 172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync  
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 myMode
xrandr --output VGA-1 --verbose --mode myMode
```

It shows the following error in the last step:

```
crtc 1:       myMode  60.00 +0+0 "VGA-1"
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
crtc 0: disable
crtc 1: disable
crtc 2: disable
screen 0: revert
crtc 0: revert
crtc 1: revert
crtc 2: revert
```

I went through these links for the crtc failed problem : ([here1](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=185937)). But it did not work.

QS? Is it a hardware problem? If not can it be fixed with some other configuration setup?

Thanks !

Comment: Any luck? Got the same problem with a 4k monitor

Comment: @FredericoSchardong, sorry no luck, I tried this one year back during my graduate school. Never tried this after.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but i figured out that xrandr uses integrated graphics card (in my case Intel) even tho i have Nvidia MX350.

You can experiment with refresh rate while. For example, I couldn't set 3440x1440_60.00hz on my external 34" monitor, but instead of 60hz I put 25hz and that was the max refresh rate I could get from this integrated graphics card.

Now I'm experimenting on how to force xrandr to use Nvidia instead of Intel gpu, because that would 100% solve the problem, since I've used this nvidia gpu for complex games and they ran in range from 60-120fps.

I hope this solves at least something, because it did for me, but it is not enough.